A claim for a Schauder basis on Hilbert spaces
Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and assume that $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset H$ is a Schauder basis for $H$ such that given any $v\in H$ there holds:
$$ v = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \langle v,e_k \rangle_H \,e_k.$$
Does it follow that $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis for $H$?

Yes. We have,
$$e_n = \sum_k \delta_{kn} e_k = \sum_k \langle e_n, e_k \rangle e_k$$
By definition of Schauder basis, this implies $\langle e_n, e_k \rangle = \delta_{kn}$ for all $k$ and for all $n$, which just means $\{e_k\}$ is orthonormal. That it is an ONB then follows immediately.
